# "Lock" a certain user to a certain user in SSH (Cygwin)?

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2008-r2, cygwin

I need to give access to a remote user via SSH (Cygwin) in a Windows 2008 R2 box, but the user must see only his `/home` folder, and cannot read, write or list contents from another folder. The user will access the server via Filezilla.

I tried to set permissions on Windows Explorer, however the user can list the content of another folders even when he appears to be prohibited to access the folder.

There's some configuration in Cygwin/SSH that can restrict the user only for his `/home` folder?

Comment: On traditional Linux systems, this is known as `chroot` jail.

Comment: What's the purpose of the user having SSH access? What is he supposed to be doing?

Comment: He needs to transfer files remotely.

Comment: @JakeGould Is it possible set `chroot` with Windows standard user permissions?

Comment: @jiyamesu No idea since I am a Mac/Linux/Unix person. But that is the path I would recommend you research & pursue.